# Want to print selectively a web page in firefox Can I do it?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, printing

I just want to print a portion of a web page.Printee is a addon for IE which can do the job in IE.Is there a facility available in firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a inverse solution to your problem:

Use the "[Nuke Anything Enhanced](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/951)" add-on for Firefox, with it delete all the content you **don't** want to print, then just print the rest.

The add-on is in active development, it's compatible up to the latest Firefox version.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, when I print there's a dialog box that pops up, and in it is a radio button called "Selection".  That seems to do what I think you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [printwhatyoulike.com](http://www.printwhatyoulike.com/).

As this is a web-based solution it should work with any browser.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest copying the bit you're interested into Word, but that doesn't preserve all the formatting:

[image]

However, it might do in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

The [Aardvark](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4111) add-on for Firefox is what you are looking for :

> Powerful and user-friendly selector
>   utility for selecting elements and
>   doing various actions on them. It can
>   be used for cleaning up a page prior
>   to printing it (by removing and
>   isolating elements), and for web
>   development